# Best way to bind this slider control to an MVC model property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Question background:**

I'm using noUiSlider to allow users to select prices between a maximum and minimum value (0 - 5000). The selected Maximum and Minimum values then need to be bound to a my views maximum and minimum properties and posted to a relevant controller method.

**The Issue:**

I'm not sure how I should go about binding this control. I have a form group that used HTML Helpers such as `TextBoxFor` which allow me to easily bind an input to a property but this is different as there is no user input instead the values are set through the nouislider javascript.

I have two labels - as shown - that display the selected values from the controller.

[image]

**Note:** As I need to post the values to the controller I have included the `Html.HiddenFor` helpers to bind the models but these are always null.

**How can I bind the values within the labels to a model in my view?**

The following code will show the situation.

**The Code:**

*nouislider setup:*

```
var snapSlider = document.getElementById('slider-snap');
    var snapValues = [
        document.getElementById('slider-snap-value-lower'),
        document.getElementById('slider-snap-value-upper')
    ];
    var range = {
        'min': 0,
        '10%': 100,
        '20%': 200,
        '30%': 400,
        '40%': 600,
        '50%': 800,
        '60%': 1000,
        '70%': 2000,
        '80%': 3000,
        '90%': 4000,
        'max': 5000
    };

noUiSlider.create(snapSlider, {
    start: [ 0, 5000 ],
    snap: true,
    connect: true,
    tooltips: true,
    range: range,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        prefix: '$',
    })
});

snapSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

snapValues[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];

});
```

*Form:*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="maxPricePad height dropWidth">
        <div class="pricePad">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Min. Price:</label>
            <span id="slider-snap-value-lower"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
             <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Max. Price:</label>
             <span id="slider-snap-value-upper"></span>
        </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.maxPrice)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.minPrice)
     </div>
  </div>
```

*Controller:*

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult UpdateResults(HomePageVM homePageSearch)
{
   //Data logic

   //return JsonResult(data);
}
```

*HomePageVM Model:*

```
public class HomePageVM
{
    public string maxPrice { set; get; }
    public string minPrice { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per their documentation, values (the first param on the callback on the update event) will be an array with the range values. Read the first and second values from this array and use that to set the input field values.

```
snapSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

  var min=values[0];
  var max=values[1];
  $("#maxPrice").val(max);
  $("#minPrice").val(min);

});
```

Also you need to make sure that your input fields(the `@Html.HiddenFor` calls) are inside a `form` tag so that when you submit the form the values will be also submitted and can be available in your action method.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/rabizegaze/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working js bin sample.

Comment: Fantatic answer. I did this as you have said in the .on event. I then change the labels for read only TextBoxFor controls and can now post the data to the controller mapping to the min and max properties.